# Can I get my outstanding IRS balance paid to my bank account?

Tags: irs, bank-account, stimulus

I am owed money from the IRS and live in Sweden.

They sent me a check but I live in Sweden and it is very expensive to cash a foreign check here (or any check for that matter).

On my tax return I filled in  my US bank account and clearing numbers (it is an account with Wise) but for whatever reason they ignored them and sent me a check to my address in Sweden instead.

Is there any way to cancel that check and instead get it as a deposit in the bank account?

Comment: Will you owe taxes next year? It might be simpler to just allow the balance to be applied to your next bill. As I understand it, the IRS won't do direct deposit to foreign banks, but it is odd that they would not deposit to your US bank account. I would call or write to ask for an explanation, and to request that the money be deposited according to your instructions.

Comment: Since you have a US bank account, can't you simply endorse the check and mail it to the bank?  Indeed, I understand that there are cell phone apps that will let you deposit a check by taking a picture of it.  Search for "mobile check deposit".

Comment: When you say "US Account", to clarify do you mean 'Bank account in the US" or "USD account with a bank in Sweden"?

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon a bank account in the US is what I mean

Comment: @jamessqf Wise is an international banking service which allows you to open what appears to be kind-of-accounts i.e. you can create a US dollar account which has US bank account and clearing number but it doesn't have the ability to cash checks or other normal bank features

Comment: @chepner I won't owe taxes , likely for many years but I can try requesting by phone

Comment: @Cameron Ah, I wonder if the IRS does not consider that a domestic account, then.

Comment: @chepner they are based in the US but maybe somehow it still doesn't count?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like they are not a bank, just a business that facilitates international money transfers. That's probably a distinction the IRS cares about.

Comment: Since what you have is apparently not a "real" bank account, do you have a friend in the US who would deposit the check in their account?  (Of course I mean a real friend, not some random internet person :-)) That seems like the only option,

Comment: @jamessqf I do have relatives in the US, are they able to deposit it without my presence?

Comment: @Cameron: Yes.  This is called a "third party check". You would need to "endorse" the check - that is, sign it on the back - and mail it to them.  (Don't know about electronic deposit for 3rd party checks.)  A search for that term gives lots of hits.